# How to integrate mmenu jQuery plugin with ReactJS and Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, reactjs, mmenu

So here we are, innovating with Meteor and ReactJS. This is what i did:

1. Copied the mmenu jQuery plugin inside my `client/lib/js/` folder.
2. Created a component called `Menu` which has the **mmenu** plugin initialization in the `componentDidMount` method.
3. Placed the React `Menu` in my `Layout` component, so this how the React tree looked in Chrome when inspected:

   `<Layout>
       <Menu user={this.data.user} />
       <Home />
   </Layout>`

Problem is, when the `Menu` component renders, the **mmenu** plugin **moves** the corresponding DOM (the `nav` element) outside of React scope (just bellow the `body` tag), so React get confused when referencing that unexistent component when it tries to re-render it when `user` object (passed as props) changes.

The `Menu` component looks like this:

```
Menu = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount(){
        const menu = $(this.refs['mmenu']);
        menu.mmenu({ /* some options here */ });
    }
    render(){
        <nav id="menu" ref="mmenu">
            { this.props.user ? <HomePublic/> : <HomePrivate/> }
        </nav>
    }
});
```

As you can see, when invoking `menu.mmenu()` function, the plugin **moves** the `nav` element to the body, which looks like this:

```
<body>
  <nav ...> </nav>
  <div id="react-root"> ... </div>
</body>
```

So my question is: Is there a way to do this so React can re-render the component without errors?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, not to use jQuery at all (and the plugins), when you are using React. Because React Handles its Virtual DOM. jQuery Mmenu manipulates the Real DOM, so this will not work together and React it is not designed to work with jQuery.

Check out, if there is a already a ReactComponent, which you could use to solve you task. Otherwise, if you really depend on jQuery, you are maybe better with Blaze (in terms of Meteor)

Comment: Hi, i'm migrating my app from Blaze to React. There is no mmenu component for React, so if i really want to use mmenu plugin is through jQuery.

Comment: mmenu is a jquery plugin.. how about this one: http://negomi.github.io/react-burger-menu/

Comment: I tried that, but I  could not made it work. Finally I tweaked a bit with mmenu, told react not to re render we component and modified the dom directly with jQuery. It's not ideal but at least it works